# tensorflow: two models initialized in two separate graphs but they seen only in last one graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class SimpleModel():
    pass

def declare_placeholders(self):

    self.input_batch = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, None], name='input_batch') 

SimpleModel.__declare_placeholders = classmethod(declare_placeholders) 

def init_model(self):
    self.__declare_placeholders()

SimpleModel.__init__ = classmethod(init_model)

g_1 = tf.Graph()
with g_1.as_default():
    model1 = SimpleModel()

g_2 = tf.Graph()
with g_2.as_default(): 
    model2 = SimpleModel()
```

I'dont expect AssertionError in next situation:

```
assert model1.input_batch.graph is g_1

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-1ffc6a2e45a2> in <module>
----> 1 assert model1.input_batch.graph is g_1

AssertionError:
```

But I see next:

```
assert model1.input_batch.graph is g_2 (????)
```

But I've initialized model1 inside g_1!

How can I modify SimpleModel to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've have solve problem: use class definition without pass and classmethod

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class SimpleModel():

    def declare_placeholders(self):    
        self.input_batch = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, None], name='input_batch') 

    def __init__(self):
        self.declare_placeholders()

g_1 = tf.Graph()
with g_1.as_default():
    model1 = SimpleModel()

g_2 = tf.Graph()
with g_2.as_default(): 
    model2 = SimpleModel()
```

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this to load 2 different models in 2 separate graphs:

Here PATH_TO_MODEL_CKPT is the path of the saved model file or you can construct the model inside the graph.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
import os

class Graph1(object):
    def __init__(self, PATH_TO_MODEL_CKPT):
        graph1 = tf.Graph()
        with self.graph1.as_default():
            model_exp = os.path.expanduser(PATH_TO_CKPT)
            print('Model filename: %s' % model_exp)
            od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
                serialized_graph = fid.read()
                od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
                tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

                sess1 = tf.Session(graph=graph1)

class Graph2(object):
    def __init__(self, PATH_TO_MODEL_CKPT):
        graph2 = tf.Graph()
        with self.graph2.as_default():
            model_exp = os.path.expanduser(PATH_TO_CKPT)
            print('Model filename: %s' % model_exp)
            od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
                serialized_graph = fid.read()
                od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
                tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
                sess2 = tf.Session(graph=graph2)
```